# Как запушить задеплоенный код на Heroku

Tags: python-3.x, heroku

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Залил на Heroku идентичный код с такими же файлами, что и на этом [GitHub](https://github.com/Alexitmisty/raspis8181). Всё задеплоилось, однако в разделе Resources всё так же висит

> This app has no process types yet

То есть запушить до конца я не могу.
Как это исправить?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Скорее всего, нужно добавить procfile (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile)

Comment: @ArthurKupriyanov Он уже есть, может, надо прописать что-то конкретное?

Comment: А что вы прописали?

Comment: @ArthurKupriyanov bot: python3 raspisanie.py
Я залез в логи и там написано "error code=H14 desc="No web processes running""
В инете есть совет прописать через консоль "heroku ps:scale web=1"
Однако оно выдает "Couldn't find that process type (web)."

Comment: попробуйте использовать не bot, а worker. То есть worker: python3 raspisanie.py

Comment: @ArthurKupriyanov Ничего не изменилось

Comment: а если прописать в консоль "heroku ps:scale worker=1"

Comment: @ArthurKupriyanov Опять же безрезультатно

Comment: я посмотрел ваш репозиторий. Переименуйте procfile в Procfile. Если это не поможет или изменит хоть что-то, то я уже не знаю что делать

Comment: @ArthurKupriyanov Спасибо, помогло. После того, как название Procfile прописалось с заглавной, Heroku всё увидел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Напишу чтобы люди с похожей проблемой смогли её решить.

Сначала убедитесь что вы создали файл `Procfile`, при этом следует заметить, что важно соблюдать регистр. Например, `procfile` будет уже не валиден, также неправильным именованием является указание расширения. Таким образом, `Procfile.txt` так же является ошибочным. Просто `Procfile`.

Во внутренностях `Procfile` следует учесть, что есть два вида процессов: `web` и `worker`. Подробнее: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile .

Из heroku devcenter:

> Web: Web dynos are dynos of the “web” process type that is defined in your Procfile. Only web dynos receive HTTP traffic from the routers.
>
> Worker: Worker dynos can be of any process type declared in your Procfile, other than “web”. Worker dynos are typically used for background jobs, queueing systems, and timed jobs. You can have multiple kinds of worker dynos in your application. For example, one for urgent jobs and another for long-running jobs.